# Issues when restoring state of a Fragment in ViewPager (with FragmentStatePagerAdapter)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I will have trouble explaining what is the problem here, but I'll try.

so I have a `ViewPager` with a lot of `Fragment` in it, managed by a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, these `Fragment` are cards related to an abstract class `Question` that has multiple childs `TrueFalseQuestion`, `MultipleChoiceQuestion` etc.. But there is only 1 type of `Fragment` which is `QuestionFragment` :

```
public class QuestionFragment extends ElementFragment {

    public static String ARG_DATA = "c0pcjOLtwAoIMDe1lwJ4";
    protected static String ARG_SOURCE = "source";
    protected static String ARG_ANWSER_CORRECTION = "LPYmZpVmnhssq762mLpu";
    protected static String ARG_COURSE_MODE = "COURSEMODE";

    protected ElementViewerActivity.Source source;


    protected Question mQuestion;
    protected QuestionType mQtype;

    protected CollectedAnswers userAnswer;
    protected QuestionAnswerResponse serverResponse;

    protected QuestionViewHolder holder;

    private CourseMode mCourseMode;



    /*Lot of different newInstance here, I don't think they are relevant*/

    public QuestionFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        //Log.i("renaud", "savingInstanceState : userAnswer==null?:" + (userAnswer == null) + " | serverResponse==null?:" + (serverResponse == null));
        outState.putSerializable("userAnswer", userAnswer);
        outState.putSerializable("serverResponse", serverResponse);
        Log.i("renaud","question fragment state saved");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mQuestion = (Question) getArguments().get(ARG_DATA);
        Log.e("ID ",this.toString());

        setRetainInstance(true);

        source = (ElementViewerActivity.Source) getArguments().get(ARG_SOURCE);
        mCourseMode = (CourseMode) getArguments().get(ARG_COURSE_MODE);

        QuestionAnswerCorrection questionAnswerCorrection = (QuestionAnswerCorrection) getArguments().get(ARG_ANWSER_CORRECTION);
        if(questionAnswerCorrection!= null && savedInstanceState==null){
            userAnswer = questionAnswerCorrection.userAnswer;
            serverResponse = questionAnswerCorrection.serverResponse;
        }

        mQtype = mQuestion.getQtype();

        Activity activity = getActivity();

        switch (mQtype) {
            case TRUE_FALSE:
                holder = new QuestionTFViewHolder(activity, mQuestion);
                Log.e("DEBUG --TF-- ","holder = new QuestionTFViewHolder(activity, mQuestion)");
                break;
            case MULTIPLE_CHOICES:
                holder = new QuestionMCViewHolder(activity, mQuestion);
                Log.e("DEBUG --MC-- ","holder = new QuestionMCViewHolder(activity, mQuestion)");
                break;
            case ORDER:
                holder = new QuestionOrderViewHolder(activity, mQuestion);
                break;
            case LINKER:
                holder = new QuestionLinkerViewHolder(activity, mQuestion);
                break;
            case OPEN:
                holder = new QuestionOpenViewHolder(activity, mQuestion);
                break;
            case AREA:
                holder = new QuestionAreaViewHolder(activity, mQuestion);
                break;
            default:
                Log.e("renaud", "Question non traitée " + mQtype);
                break;
        }
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {

            Log.i("renaud","restore onCreateView :"+mQtype.name());

            Serializable serializedUserAnswer = savedInstanceState.getSerializable("userAnswer");

            if(serializedUserAnswer instanceof BooleanCollectedAnswer){
                userAnswer = (BooleanCollectedAnswer) serializedUserAnswer;
                Log.e("renaud","serializedUserAnswer instanceof BooleanCollectedAnswer");
            } else if(serializedUserAnswer instanceof CoordinateCollectedAnswer) {
                userAnswer = (CoordinateCollectedAnswer) serializedUserAnswer;
                Log.e("renaud","serializedUserAnswer instanceof CoordinateCollectedAnswer");
            } else if (serializedUserAnswer instanceof IntegerListCollectedAnswer) {
                userAnswer = (IntegerListCollectedAnswer) serializedUserAnswer;
                Log.e("renaud","serializedUserAnswer instanceof IntegerListCollectedAnswer");
            } else if (serializedUserAnswer instanceof OpenCollectedAnswer) {
                userAnswer = (OpenCollectedAnswer) serializedUserAnswer;
                Log.e("renaud","serializedUserAnswer instanceof OpenCollectedAnswer");
            }else{
                Log.e("renaud","bug");
            }
            //userAnswer = (CollectedAnswers) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("userAnswer");
            serverResponse = (QuestionAnswerResponse) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("serverResponse");
            Log.i("renaud", "Question fragment SAVED INSTANCE STATE NOT NULL (userAnswer==null)=" + (userAnswer == null) + " | (serverResponse==null):" + (serverResponse == null));
        }

        View v = null;
        switch (mQtype) {
            case TRUE_FALSE:
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question_container, container, false);
                break;
            case MULTIPLE_CHOICES:
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question_container, container, false);
                break;
            case ORDER:
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question_container, container, false);
                break;
            case LINKER:
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question_container, container, false);
                break;
            case OPEN:
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question_container, container, false);
                break;
            case AREA:
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question_container, container, false);
            default:
                Log.e("renaud", "Question non traitée " + mQtype);
                break;
        }

        holder.initWithView(v, new SendResponseOnClicListener());
        //Quand une question est vue dans l'elementViewer, cad lancé depuis le news feed, on ne peut pas envoyer la réponse.
        if (source == ElementViewerActivity.Source.VIEWER) {
            holder.sendAnswer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if (serverResponse != null || userAnswer != null) {
            //Log.i("renaud", "server response != null ? " + (serverResponse != null));
            //Log.i("renaud", "userAnswer != null ? " + (userAnswer != null));

            Log.i("renaud","savedInstanceState != null, (userAnswer!=null):"+(userAnswer!=null));

            holder.setCollectedAnswers(userAnswer);
            holder.answerSentSetDisable();
            if(mCourseMode !=null && mCourseMode == CourseMode.TRAINING) {
                holder.fillCorrection(serverResponse);
            }

            /*if(holder instanceof QuestionMCViewHolder){
                QuestionMCViewHolder mcViewHolder = (QuestionMCViewHolder) holder;
                for(int i = 0; i< mcViewHolder.mcLayout.getChildCount();i++){
                    Log.i("Renaud","test dans question fragment :"+((CheckBox) mcViewHolder.mcLayout.getChildAt(i)).isChecked());
                }
            }*/

        }

        return v;
    }

    public void logTest(){

        if(holder instanceof QuestionMCViewHolder){
            Log.i("renaud","it's a question mc view holder");
            QuestionMCViewHolder mcViewHolder = (QuestionMCViewHolder) holder;
            for(int i = 0; i< mcViewHolder.mcLayout.getChildCount();i++){
                Log.i("Renaud","test dans question fragment :"+((CheckBox) mcViewHolder.mcLayout.getChildAt(i)).isChecked());
            }
        } else if(holder instanceof QuestionOrderViewHolder) {
            Log.i("renaud","it's a QuestionOrderViewHolder");
        } else if (holder instanceof QuestionLinkerViewHolder) {
            Log.i("renaud","it's a QuestionLinkerViewHolder");
        } else if (holder instanceof QuestionTFViewHolder) {
            Log.i("renaud","it's a QuestionTFViewHolder");
        } else if (holder instanceof QuestionOpenViewHolder) {
            Log.i("renaud","it's a QuestionOpenViewHolder");
        } else if (holder instanceof QuestionAreaViewHolder) {
            Log.i("renaud","it's a QuestionAreaViewHolder");
        }else{
            Log.e("ID ",this.toString());
            Log.i("renaud","holder is nothing!");
            Log.i("renaud","holder ==null ?"+(holder==null));
            Log.i("renaud","(holder instanceof QuestionViewHolder) ?"+(holder instanceof QuestionViewHolder));

        }
    }


    public class SendResponseOnClicListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {

            holder.answerSentSetDisable();


            //TODO ARE ALL DOCUMENTS UPLOADED WHEN IT'S AN OPEN QUESTION ?

            //final QuestionOpenViewHolder openHolder = (QuestionOpenViewHolder) holder;
            userAnswer = holder.collectAnswer();


            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        final QuestionAnswerResponse response =
                                CourseRepository.getInstance().postQuestionAnswer(mQuestion.getId(), mQuestion.getCreatedFor(), userAnswer);

                        EventBus.getDefault().post(new EnableNextEvent(mQuestion.getId()));

                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                serverResponse = response;
                                if(mCourseMode !=null && mCourseMode == CourseMode.TRAINING) {
                                    holder.fillCorrection(serverResponse);
                                }
                                //holder.fillCorrection(response);
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();


        }
    }

    public class AnswerCollectedEvent {
        public CollectedAnswers userAnswer;
        public QuestionAnswerResponse serverResponse;
        public String questionId;

        public AnswerCollectedEvent(String questionId, CollectedAnswers userAnswer, QuestionAnswerResponse serverResponse) {
            this.userAnswer = userAnswer;
            this.questionId = questionId;
            this.serverResponse = serverResponse;
        }
    }

    public static class EnableNextEvent {

        public String id;

        public EnableNextEvent(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        //EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        //EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        super.onStart();
    }


}
```

So I have to save the input of the user & the answer sent by the server on onSaveInstanceState for it to be reconstruct correctly on config changes.

But when I change orientation, I loose the user input.

You'll find a method called `public void logTest()` that I created to see what is the problem. I call it when the viewPager changes its pages and it seems that I always get these logs :

```
E/ID: QuestionFragment{edb2fad}
holder is nothing!
holder ==null ?true
(holder instanceof QuestionViewHolder) ?false
```

and the Id of the fragment is different from the one in the onCreate which look like that :

```
/ID: QuestionFragment{68fc4ae #1 id=0x7f0e00a5}
```

So I thought that I have twice the Fragment and that the wrong one was displayed but in my Activity onCreate I test how much Fragment I have :

```
mPagerAdapter.addItem(QuestionFragment.newInstance(question, ElementViewerActivity.Source.PLAYER, mCourseMode));
Log.e("renaud", "restore count mPagerAdapter : " + mPagerAdapter.getFragmentResgisteredCount());
```

and it seem that I have the good amount. So I create Fragments Every Logs indicated that they have the corrects user inputs, I add them one by one to my adapter that sais that there are the only ones in it, but when I switch pages, and call that :

```
Log.i("renaud","page selected "+position);
Fragment fragment = mPagerAdapter.getItem(position);
if(fragment instanceof QuestionFragment){
   Log.i("renaud","it's a question fragment");
   ((QuestionFragment) fragment).logTest();
}
```

log test is called but with the result I gave above...

--- EDIT ---

```
public class QuestionMCViewHolder extends QuestionViewHolder {

    public LinearLayout mcLayout;

    public QuestionMCViewHolder(Activity activity, Question question) {
        super(activity, question);
    }

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    @Override
    public void initWithView(View v, QuestionFragment.SendResponseOnClicListener onClicListener) {

        Log.i("renaud","QuestionMCViewHolder initWithView");

        super.initWithView(v, onClicListener);

        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mActivity);
        container.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question_container_mc, null));
        mcLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.mc_layout);

        for (String text : question.getAnswers()) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question_container_mc_item, null);
            cb.setText(text);
            cb.setChecked(false);
            mcLayout.addView(cb);
        }


    }


    @Override
    public void fillCorrection(QuestionAnswerResponse answer) {
        super.fillCorrection(answer);


        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question_container_mc, null);
        LinearLayout answerLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.mc_layout);


        for (Integer position : answer.getAnswers()) {
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question_container_mc_item, null);


            cb.setText(question.getAnswers().get(position));
            cb.setChecked(true);
            cb.setEnabled(false);
            //cb.setBackgroundResource(R.color.question_true);
            answerLayout.addView(cb);
        }
        correctionSpecificContainer.addView(v);

        AnimationUtils.expand(correctionLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public IntegerListCollectedAnswer collectAnswer() {

        IntegerListCollectedAnswer answer = new IntegerListCollectedAnswer();
        for (int i = 0; i < mcLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if (((CheckBox) mcLayout.getChildAt(i)).isChecked()) {
                answer.list.add(i);
            }
        }
        return answer;
    }

    @Override
    public void setCollectedAnswers(CollectedAnswers answers) {

        Log.w("renaud","QuestionMCViewHolder setCollectedAnswers");

        if (answers instanceof IntegerListCollectedAnswer) {
            IntegerListCollectedAnswer integers = (IntegerListCollectedAnswer) answers;

            //mcLayout.removeAllViews();

            for (int i = 0; i < question.getAnswers().size(); i++) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) mcLayout.getChildAt(i);  //inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question_container_mc_item, null);
                //cb.setText(question.getAnswers().get(i));
                //Log.i("QUESTIONMC SETCOLLECTED", "integers.list.contains(i) = " + integers.list.contains(i));

                //mcLayout.addView(cb);
                cb.setChecked(integers.list.contains(i));
                Log.d("renaud", "setCollectedAnswers cb.isChecked():"+cb.isChecked());
            }



        } else {
            Log.i("renaud", "CollectedAnswers instanceof IntegerListCollectedAnswer failed");
        }


    }
}
```

---

```
public class IntegerListCollectedAnswer extends CollectedAnswers {
    public ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public IntegerListCollectedAnswer(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public IntegerListCollectedAnswer() {
    }
}
```

---

```
public class PlayerPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        //private SparseArray<ElementFragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<>();
        private ArrayList<ElementFragment> registeredFragments = new ArrayList<>();


        /*public void restoreFragment(ArrayList<ElementFragment> registeredFragments, int position) {
            this.registeredFragments = registeredFragments;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            switchToItem(position);
        }*/

        public int getFragmentResgisteredCount(){
            return registeredFragments.size();
        }

        public PlayerPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return Math.min(registeredFragments.size(),mMaxIndexQuestionAllowed + 1);
        }

        public void addItem(ElementFragment elementFragment) {
            registeredFragments.add(elementFragment);
        }


        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return registeredFragments.get(position);
        }


    }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show your FragmenStatePagerAdapter class? Most important methods are getItem and instantiateItem